# Modifying Alarms Which Trigger Services Based on Screen Status

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-broadcast

I am currently starting a service using a Broadcast Receiver which fires 60 seconds after the  device boots up. This broadcast receiver triggers an alarm so that my service runs every 60 seconds. Code for this is as follows:

```
public class ScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // Restart service every 60 seconds
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 60;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, StartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Start 60 seconds after boot completed
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
        // Fetch every 60 seconds
        // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
    }
}
```

The above starts the service as follows:

```
public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, PhotoService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

I would like to somehow modify this so that my service runs every 60 seconds when the phone screen is on and every 20 minutes when off.

What is the best way to do this ? Can I modify the alarm dynamically when the screen is switched off/on ?

Thanks for any help,

Regards,

Fido

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have found out how to do this so I thought I would put this here in case anyone else is ever curious. (More elegant solutions are always welcome):

First thing is that in my service I added the following to the OnCreate:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
     BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScheduleReceiver();
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
 }
```

This is done so that my broadcast receiver can handle those events.  Apparently you cannot register these via intent-filters in the xml.

This means that when the service is created it ensures that these additional system actions can be handled.

I then modified my broadcast receiver to be:

```
public class ScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int ALARM_ID = 909;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);   
        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, StartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_ID, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        service.cancel(pending);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); //Delay startup by one minute - This is useful to prevent over utilization of resources at boot

        // Start alarm. Set a long repeat time if the screen is off and a short repeat time if the screen is on
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pending);
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 600000, pending);
        }
    }
}
```

From the above I cancel any current alarms with the same pending intent and then I set a new alarm whenever the screen if switched off/on.

This seems to be working for me. As always any improvements are very welcome.